# How to Delete Files Using SSH in a Certain Directory

Tags: shell-script, ssh

What code can I use to delete all files with extension .jpg.webp inside the wp-content/uploads/2019/01 via SSH terminal on a remote Linux machine? I only want to delete all .jpg.webp files inside that directory and retain all .jpg.webp in other directories. Thank you.

Comment: Recursively or only inside this very directory and no subdirectories?

Comment: @DevilaN just inside that very directory in wordpress. I have access to the SSH terminal via cpanel and since there are thousands of .jpg.webp files inside, I can't delete them manually. I only need to delete all the .jpg.webp extension files inside that wp-content/uploads/2019/01 folder.

Comment: Login via SSH, then `rm -f wp-content/uploads/2019/01/*.jpg.webp`.

Comment: @JiriB I am getting this error `rm: cannot remove 'wp-content/uploads/2019/01/*.jpg.webp': No such file or directory`

Comment: @JiriB please post an answer instead of a comment so the question can be marked as answered. Also, unless you know `-f` is needed, it is better to avoid using it.

Comment: @KitaChre you need to use the full path to the directory. When you `ssh`, you arrive in your user's home directory. Unless the `wp-content` directory is a subdirectory of your home, you will need to use the full path to it. Something like `/var/www/wp-content/uploads/2019/01` perhaps? We cannot know the path if you don't tell us.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can just ssh and then (make sure you are in proper directory first or provide FULL PATH to directory!):
`rm wp-content/uploads/2019/01/*.jpg.webp`

But if there is a lot of files then things might get complicated. `*.jpg.webp` file expands into a long list of names in bash, and it refuses to feed `rm` command properly leading.

As a fallback you may use `find` command to search and execute command upon searched files.

```
find wp-content/uploads/2019/01/ -name '*.jpg.webp' -maxdepth 1 -exec rm {} +
```

This translates into following parts:

- `find wp-content/uploads/2019/01/` go through directory content.
- `-name '*.jpg.webp'` finding files with name ending in `.jpg.webp`.
- `-maxdepth 1` says that find should only go 1 level deep (which is current directory it is using). IMPORTANT: this only works if the remote machine is using Linux or otherwise has GNU `find`.
- `-exec rm {} +` means execute `rm` for each file found; the `+` makes it group the files into batches to run fewer commands.

Comment: Modern `find` could just use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} \;`, BTW it's much fast to use `-exec rm {} +` (it works like `xargs` works).

Comment: @JiriB it isn't about "modern", `-delete` is a GNU option and we don't know if the OP is using Linux.

Comment: @terdon Yes, I am currently using Linux.